# What are the differences between skylighting, pygments and Linguist?

Tags: haskell, syntax-highlighting, pandoc, pygments, github-linguist

Aside from being written in haskell, python and ruby, what are the main differences between [`skylighting`](https://github.com/jgm/skylighting), [`pygments`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main) and [`Linguist`](https://github.com/github/linguist)?

Do they vary widely in the language support? Do they have different internal structures? To what extent can they be used interchangeably? Are there any automatic tools for comparing the effects of their application (possibly in the vein of [babelmark](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/) for markdown)?

Is there a list of all the tools/organisations that these different tools are used? Pygments has a list of ["who uses pygments"](http://pygments.org/faq/#who-uses-pygments), and it's clear that skylighting is used by pandoc and Linguist is used by GitHub, but are there other major tools that use these?